Re-entering France with a Blue Card after 2+ years of absence
I used to live and work in France for a few years - initially I had a 4-year long Blue Card that I renewed for another 4-year Blue Card. The current card is valid through March 2025. After I had renewed the card, I voluntarily stopped my employment in France and left France and EU to live and work in another country. I have been out of France/EU for 2+ years now.
I need to return to the Schengen area. I’m planning to use my French Blue Card to enter Schengen area via France. However, I’m not sure if my Blue Card is still valid. Some lawyers I consulted with say that since I have long left France and no longer employed there, my Blue Card should no longer be valid. Others say there is no law of cancellation of the Blue Card in France and as such, unless I was explicitly informed by Prefecture that my Card is revoked, it can still be used to return, live and perhaps even work in France until March 2025. I have no idea if Prefecture ever initiated the revocation of my card (who knows, maybe they sent me a paper mail to my old mailbox that I no longer have access to?).
I also wonder what my status could be if, say, Prefecture indeed revoked / voided my Blue Card unbeknownst to me, but the France border patrol doesn’t know that and would allow me into the country nevertheless. Does this mean I would be staying in France illegally while having no idea about it?
Obviously I don’t want to break any laws and want to avoid problems and repercussions for doing something wrong.
I would appreciate your thoughts on the following:

Do you believe my Blue Card is still valid for entry / stay in France / Schengen and on what grounds?
What is the likelihood France border control becomes suspicious that I try to use a Blue Card to entry after 2+ years of absence?
Can France border control have access to my employment history and check status of my Blue Card (e.g. whether Prefecture revoked it or not)?
If I’m denied entry at the French border, what could be the repercussions for me? Am I facing any severe consequences?
If I’m allowed entry but in the meantime, hypothetically, my Card had been revoked by Prefecture, what is my legal status in France / Schengen area then?

[Edited by the author to simplify the case and the questions.]

Why do you expect a better answer here than what you got from the lawyers? Even if someone was in a similar situation, their outcome is not necessary a prediction to yours.

Thanks for your comment! Having researched this site, I feel there are people here very knowledgeable about the law, so I wouldn’t mind their opinion. I also hope that someone might be aware of similar cases, although I agree with you that every case is unique.

Thanks for your response @Relaxed. To clarify, a lawyer who said that the Blue Card should no longer be valid referred to the law (I believe) or the rules (e.g. according to them, on paper it’s no longer valid, in practice it’s a different story), but other lawyers didn’t cite or refer to any such law and even said it should be valid, hence my confusion. If the Prefecture had sent a letter to my former address it’s very unlikely I would’ve received it to my current address (nobody would bother to forward it to me and there wouldn’t even be my name in the old mailbox).

Your previous employer may well have advised the authorities when you stopped your employment. You certainly no longer meet the eligibility requirements for your Blue Card as far as I can see. I would not risk attempting to enter France using your card if I were you, but then I am very risk-averse where Immigration matters are concerned.

Thanks @Traveller. What do you think the risks are? For example, if I learn at the border that my card was invalidated, what could be the repercussions?

@Bono Denial of entry is the obvious repercussion. Which could harm any future visa applications to Schengen or anywhere else that asks applicants about prior immigration history, and would mean you’d have to buy a ticket back to your home country (or another country you can legally enter) at the spot rate.


Recently, I signed a job offer in EU / Schengen area country (not France). For various reasons, I can’t apply for a work visa to that country directly. Instead, I need to first return to the Schengen area, then travel to that destination country from within the Schengen area, and then apply from within that country to a residence permit.

Are you positive that's the case? That seems unusual. Is your future job also a Blue Card job?

I’m planning to use my French Blue Card to enter Schengen area via France and then proceed with my plan outlined above. However, I’m not sure if my Blue Card is still valid. I have consulted multiple immigration lawyers and read a ton of articles and it’s still unclear. Some lawyers say that since I have long left France and no longer employed there, my Blue Card should no longer be valid. Others say there is no law of cancellation of the Blue Card in France and as such, unless I was explicitly informed by Prefecture that my Card is revoked, it can still be used to return, live and perhaps even work in France until March 2025.

There is no contradiction here. There is indeed no way for a French residence permit to implicitly become invalid, it requires a decision by the préfecture. The person who told you that the permit should no longer be valid might have been trying to convey that there is a significant risk that it did happen. As you did not fulfill the conditions of your permit (you did not have a job in France anymore), the préfecture was certainly allowed to do that.

I have no idea if Prefecture ever initiated the revocation of my card (who knows, maybe they sent me a paper mail to my old mailbox that I no longer have access to?) and I’m hesitant to check with them.

That's the problem, if you don't know, how do you want us to guess? If you already have got the opinion of “multiple” lawyers, how is an additional opinion going to resolve the issue?

Thank you @Relaxed. I’m quite sure the process is sound in my destination country. I don’t want to get into specific complexities of my case (e.g. why can’t I simply apply to a work visa in such country) as it’s irrelevant to this particular question. Regarding my status in France, I guess the question is – if the Prefecture had revoked my Blue Card, will I learn about this at the border upon my attempt to return? Or will border control not know themselves?

The border control will most definitely know.

@Bono I was not asking about the reasons why you can or cannot apply for a work visa where you are right now, my question is whether you would be able to apply for a work permit in this other Schengen country based on your French Blue Card. Those are two different questions, it's not because it's difficult or impossible to apply outside the country that you will be allowed to do it in-country. Also note that there is a third possibility, namely applying in France. If you were really living in France, that would be the regular procedure.

Regarding what border guards might know, if that's what you want to know then ask about that and edit out all the hard-to-answer speculative questions. In short, they won't have access to your work history but they can presumably see if your card has been invalidated and definitely if you had an OQTF.
